# How to disable SSL (https) streaming and force http streaming

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I need to disable "https delivery of videos from YouTube player Api", is there a way to achieve "http streaming (No ssl)" from "googlevideo Domain" through an option of the "iframe player" or something else ?